# Numpy [...,None]

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have found myself needing to add features to existing numpy arrays which has led to a question around what the last portion of the following code is actually doing:

```
   np.ones(shape=feature_set.shape)[...,None]
```

**Set-up**

As an example, let's say I wish to solve for linear regression parameter estimates by using numpy and solving:

[image: From Elements of Statistical Learning]

Assume I have a feature set shape (50,1), a target variable of shape (50,), and I wish to use the shape of my target variable to add a column for intercept values.

It would look something like this:

```
# Create random target & feature set
y_train = np.random.randint(0,100, size = (50,))
feature_set = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(50,1))

# Build a set of 1s after shape of target variable
int_train = np.ones(shape=y_train.shape)[...,None]

# Able to then add int_train to feature set 
X = np.concatenate((int_train, feature_set),1)
```

**What I Think I Know**

I see the difference in output when I include [...,None] vs when I leave it off. Here it is:

[image]

The second version returns an error around input arrays needing the same number of dimensions, and eventually I stumbled on the solution to use [...,None].

**Main Question**

While I see the output of [...,None] gives me what I want, I am struggling to find any information on *what* it is actually supposed to do. Can anybody walk me through what this code actually means, what the *None* argument is doing, etc?

Thank you!

Comment: You could also use `np.ones((y_train.shape[0], 1))` or `np.ones((50,1))`.  The `None` just adds a size one dimension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slice of `[..., None]` consists of two "shortcuts":

The ellipsis literal component:

> The dots (...) represent as many colons as needed to produce a complete indexing tuple. For example, if x is a rank 5 array (i.e., it has 5 axes), then
>
> - `x[1,2,...]` is equivalent to `x[1,2,:,:,:]`,
> - `x[...,3]` to `x[:,:,:,:,3]` and
> - `x[4,...,5,:]` to `x[4,:,:,5,:]`.

([Source](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c))

The `None` component:

> **`numpy.newaxis`**
>
> The `newaxis` object can be used in all slicing operations to create an axis of length one. `newaxis` is an alias for ‘None’, and ‘None’ can be used in place of this with the same result.

([Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis))

So, `arr[..., None]` takes an array of dimension `N` and "adds" a dimension "at the end" for a resulting array of dimension `N+1`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(x.shape)          # (2, 3)

y = x[...,None]
print(y.shape)          # (2, 3, 1)

z = x[:,:,np.newaxis]
print(z.shape)          # (2, 3, 1)

a = np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
print(a.shape)          # (2, 3, 1)

print((y == z).all())   # True
print((y == a).all())   # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
np.ones(shape=(2,3))[...,None].shape
```

As you see the 'None' phrase change the (2,3) matrix to a (2,3,1) tensor. As a matter of fact it put the matrix in the LAST index of the tensor.

If you use

```
np.ones(shape=(2,3))[None, ...].shape
```

it put the matrix in the FIRST‌ index of the tensor