# Python: adding index as new column to 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have np.array like below

```
dat = array([[ 0,  1,  0],
[ 1,  0,  0],
[0, 0, 1]]
)
```

What I want to do is that adding the (index of row + 1) as a new column to this array, which is like

```
newdat = array([[ 0,  1,  0, 1],
[ 1,  0,  0, 2],
[0, 0, 1, 3]]
)
```

How should I achieve this.

Comment: `concatenate` is your friend here.  Read its docs

Comment: Would this work? `np.hstack([dat, np.linspace(1, dat.shape[0], dat.shape[0]).reshape((-1, 1))])`

Comment: `np.c_[dat,1:len(dat)+1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`np.append()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815854/how-to-add-column-to-numpy-array). You can also get more info about [[...,None]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127657/numpy-none) here

```
import numpy as np

dat = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
])

a = np.array(range(1,4))[...,None] #None keeps (n, 1) shape
dat = np.append(dat, a, 1)

print (dat)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 2]
 [0 0 1 3]]
```

Or you can use hstack()

```
a = np.array(range(1,4))[...,None] #None keeps (n, 1) shape
dat = np.hstack((dat, a))
```

And as hpaulj mentioned, np.concatenate is the way to go. You can read more about [concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) documentation. Also, see additional examples of concatenate on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236926/concatenating-two-one-dimensional-numpy-arrays)

```
dat = np.concatenate([dat, a], 1)
```

Comment: Since `np.append` is misused so often, I prefer to see `dat = np.concatenate([dat, a], 1)` used instead (or of course the `hstack`).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
newdat = np.column_stack([dat, range(1,dat.shape[0] + 1)])
print(newdat)
#[[0 1 0 1]
# [1 0 0 2]
# [0 0 1 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using [`numpy.insert()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
import numpy as np

dat = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
])

dat = np.insert(dat, 3, values=[range(1, 4)], axis=1)

print(dat)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 2]
 [0 0 1 3]]
```

More generally, you can make use of [`numpy.ndarray.shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) for the appropriate sizing:

```
dat = np.insert(dat, dat.shape[1], values=[range(1, dat.shape[0] + 1)], axis=1)
```